# How to connect to Oracle DB using JDBC connection with out opening Oracle in my machine

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Hi Below is the code I wrote for connecting to Oracle DB using JDBC connection and return some values. But this code establish the connection and returns the result if I am opening the oracle toad in my machine.

But when the oracle toad is closed and try to run this code, it will not connect.

Please let me knwo how to connect to oracle DB with out opening the oracle toad manually.

```
package library;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class DBAutomationConnection {
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
  DBAutomationConnection dbconn = new DBAutomationConnection();
  //Connection conn = dbconn.DBConnection1();
  dbconn.DBConnection1("select * from employee where empid='test123'","ROLE_NAME");

}

public void DBConnection1(String query, String colName)throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
 Connection connection = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
  try {
      // Load the JDBC driver

      String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

      Class.forName(driverName);

      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//testhostname:1528/ServiceName", "XXAAA_U", "Jw9S");
      System.out.println("Connection successful: " +connection);


      try {
              stmt = connection.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
              while (rs.next()) {
                    //String UserID = rs.getString("USER_ID");
                  String UserID = rs.getString(colName);
                    System.out.println(UserID);     
              }
        } catch (SQLException e ) {
              System.out.println("Could not execute query.");
              //JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
        } finally {
              if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
        }


  } catch (SQLException e) {
                  System.out.println("Could not connect to the database");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize Oracle TNS-Listener Service from your OS settings>services. You may need to check your tns configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install ORACLE client in your system to connect oracle remotely.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Oracle Thin driver installed in your system? This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm) can guide you.